# Finding all with a JOIN query giving a single result instead of multiple

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

I have the following CakePHP code; I want it to return all rows (two in this case)

```
public function orderdetails($orderId)
{
    $Productsaleslist = $this->Productsales->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'product',
                    'alias' => 'prod',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'prod.id = Productsales.product_id'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'sales_order_address',
                    'alias' => 'sod',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'sod.id = Productsales.sales_order_address_id'
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Productsales.*',
                'prod.name',
                'prod.image_url',
                'sod.*'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Productsales.product_sales_slno' => $orderId
            )
        )
    );

    $this->set('Productsaleslist', $Productsaleslist);
}
```

`$orderId` comes from a URL parameter, and it contains the value of `product_sales_slno` (RAJ201701211485025418). This should retrieve two integers, but I'm only getting one as shown below.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: does it return both records if you omit the joined tables?

Comment: yeah its showing Mr.Bill

Comment: fixed the error

Comment: $this->Productsales->virtualFields['prodCount'] = 'SUM(`Productsales`.`total_unit`)';
$this->Productsales->virtualFields['totAmt'] = 'SUM(`Productsales`.`total_amount`)';           since i have implemented this code in model i am was not getting the result now incorporated this in controller